# Forcing object specificity in python

Tags: python

I used `class` to help in creating a list called `students`:

```
class Student(object):
    name = ""
    age = 0
    major = ""`

    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major


def make_student(name, age, major):
    return Student(name, age, major)`
```

To print from the list, this is what I thought would produce the desired result . . .

```
# First Method
for i in students:
    print i
```

but this was the output:

```
<__main__.Student object at 0x108770710>
<__main__.Student object at 0x108770790>
<__main__.Student object at 0x1087707d0>`
```

So I used:

```
# Second Method
for i in students:
    print i.name, i.age, i.major
```

and here was the output I had been hoping for:

```
John 21 Maths
Mary 22 Philosophy
Georgina 25 Biology
```

My question is why the first method doesn't result in the second methods's output, and is there a way to get the second method's output without specifying each of the individual attributes?

Comment: yes there is. I will link to duplicate. Show us how your class Student look like.

Comment: Thank you @AntonvBR

Comment: Why would you expect your first method to work like your second method? Simply put, it's behavior is not defined to work that way.

Comment: My expectation is naive, and I suspect Python is not actually creating a list somewhere the way I think it is.  My naive thinking is that there is actually a list of students with their attributes somewhere and that each could be produced by its handle, but the first method result shows I am wrong.